# 2 scheduled actions from 2 versions of the same process builder

Tags: process-builder, scheduled-action

Ok so here is what I have found out.

1. You have version 1 of process, which on record update schedules some action.
2. update the record such that the action has been scheduled from the 1. version
3. clone the process as a version 2 and activate it
4. update the record such that the action has been scheduled from the 2. version
5. now you have 2 scheduled actions as follows

[image]

And my question is if there is any know issue related to this. I searched the internet and found non. And secondly, if there is a workaround for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you note is expected to happen so there's no known issue. The actions will be completed as specified in the version of the PB that was active when the flow interview record was created.

In other words, the two separate versions don't affect each other.

- Version 1 was active, the record met criteria, and a scheduled action
  was queued.
- Version 2 was activated, the record met criteria, and a scheduled
  action was queued.
- Version 1, now deactivated, will not re-evaluate the entry
  criteria and will not affect the behavior of Version 2. The only thing that
  will change is the timing of the action if the date field it relies
  on changes [per documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.process_limits_scheduled_processing.htm&type=5).

> After you deactivate a process, the scheduled time for pending
> scheduled actions stays the same. If a deactivated process has pending
> scheduled actions and the record whose field the schedule is based on
> is changed, Salesforce recalculates the schedule for those actions.
> **After a process is deactivated, Salesforce ignores all other changes
> to the associated records**."

There's the following idea asking that [scheduled actions play nice when activated](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E3FJQA0) and there's several questions/resources about this behavior with all the pains it comes with:

- [Best to avoid Scheduled Actions in Process Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251666/best-to-avoid-scheduled-actions-in-process-builder)
- [Process Builder - Scheduled Processes in previous versions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/312305/process-builder-scheduled-processes-in-previous-versions)
- [Update version of Process Builder and Pending Scheduled Actions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180586/update-version-of-process-builder-and-pending-scheduled-actions?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [What happens to "inflight" process builders when you activate a new version](https://www.stupidsalesforcetricks.com/2020/08/what-happens-to-inflight-process.html?showComment=1620951937334#c8737820663597225861)
- [Process Builder are scheduled actions independent?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256972/process-builder-are-scheduled-actions-independent?rq=1)

---

In terms of workarounds, there's no "easy" one if you're already in this position.

Your "best" option is to [mass delete](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000340209&type=1&mode=1) existing flow interviews for that deactivated version to allow your new version to be the barrier for entry. If you did need *some* existing queued actions to fire, you would then need to data load the records based on your own manual SOQL/analysis and essentially re-trigger them.

Otherwise, **it's best to come at this from a design point of view to avoid it completely.**

1. Use [scheduled paths](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/03/schedule-your-path-in-salesforce-flow) in record-triggered Flows. See this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/343642/do-scheduled-paths-get-evaluated-canceled-when-record-triggered-flow-version-cha) to confirm they're not afflicted with the same versioning issue. You should be favoring Flow over Process Builder at this point for any new automation.