# Approval process won't trigger record-triggered flow

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, workflow, bug

I want to follow up on my previous [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/353237/2-scheduled-actions-from-2-versions-of-the-same-process-builder). Because of some version issues with process builder, we wanted to move some apex action invocation to record-triggered flow with [scheduled path](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/03/schedule-your-path-in-salesforce-flow). The condition to trigger this flow is `Status = waiting for approval`. Then we have an approval process which in its initial submission action have field update wf which sets `Status = waiting for approval` and the re-evaluation is set to true, but the flow is not triggered.

Is this some feature or bug?

Comment: it is a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000003xVKQAY)

Comment: thanks for the know issue

Comment: Just commenting here to say this also applies to Before-Save RT Flows, although the Known Issue currently says it's only for After-Save Flows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed as of Spring '22

Comment: Note that if you have an existing Record-triggered flow that was created before Spring '22, you need to resave it using the Spring '22 'API Version' of 54 (or higher) in order to have it trigger this way. (See https://drive.google.com/file/d/178CjjDB5obFdVQnKBTwZQSO64gnFZcz2/view?usp=sharing) Salesforce did this so that existing flows wouldn't suddenly start triggering unexpectedly.

Comment: a record-triggered flow which I just created in a sandbox org, and is using API v54, is still not being triggered upon an update made by an approval process field update. Any idea why the fix isn't working for me?

Comment: This known issue seems to not apply to scheduled paths. I've done extensive testing and while the "Run Immediately" path works just fine as of Spring '22 (v54) I have not been able to find a workaround (besides using PB) to trigger a scheduled path from an Approval Process field update.

Comment: @tomulent, what you're referring to has just been fixed so it should get patched into Spring '22 in the next two weeks.  Garywoo, my guess is you might be getting hit by the same issue with async paths.

Comment: Can confirm it was fully patched as of 3/3/2022 (https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000pOrNQAU)